# Height targeted media queries

Tags: css, media-queries

I am implementing a Phonegap application but this is where I am confused. I need to display header and footer for my application and I have written media query like below for different screen designs

```
@media only screen and (min-height:320px){

}
```

but the problem is if I check it in Desktop browser 320px looks way big, but when I open the same in mobile devices it is looking very small. The device I have tested in is

```
Videocon Android 4.1, 480x762
```

And most popular media query templates are depending on `min-width` and `max-width` of mobiles . For my situation in my desktop 60px height header looks reasonably sized and in mobile device it is too small. How can I solve this. Somebody please help me understand this.

Comment: Just change the height for the widths, even though height is affected, check device width and update codes from there

Comment: @AndyHolmes The problem is not with updating width to height. Same height is looking different in different mobiles(resolutions).

Comment: Yeah so for each browser width override the height to look how you want it to. It's a bit difficult to see your issue without, well, seeing your issue. Pop some code online or add/link some screenshots

Comment: Did set the viewport meta tag in your html?

Comment: Yes, try using the viewport tag to set the scale of the page.

Comment: @donnywals Yes it is.

Comment: I found some clue by digging into `dpi` values. Seems I need to provide dpi values as well in media queries